# If order of the element $a^5$ is 12 can we make any guess about the order of the element $a$ in a group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If order of the element $a^5$ is 12 can we make any guess about the order of the element $a$ in a group $G$?

Could anybody clear my this doubt?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Let order of element $a$ is $n$
then $order (a^m) = \dfrac {n}{(m, n)}$, where $(m, n)$ is the gcd of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: That mean we can have $12 = \dfrac{n}{(12, n)} then possible value of n will be be the answer?

Comment: No, @monalisa. You know that $$12=\frac{n}{\gcd(5,n)}.$$ Given that $5$ is a prime there aren't too many choices for $\gcd(5,n)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh I misread. Thanks .